# How can I avoid the MarshalException for Java RMI?

Tags: java, methods, marshalling, rmi

I just finished a small program with java rmi and somehow it doesn't work. Everytime I want to start the server I'm getting the MarshalException. Are there any important points that I should be aware of them on how to implement the interface for the remote method invocation? I thought it would be possible to create an implementation but also include some additional methods like a constructor or private variables inside of the implementing class.

Shouldn't this just work?

Greetings

Comment: if my answer doesn't solve the issue, please provide more details about the exception - the whole exception (incl.message and stacktrace), for example ;)

Answer (score 3):

In order to be able to transfer objects you need to make them implement `Serializable`. And perhaps have a default (no-arg) constructor (this is not a requirement for serialization though)

As helios noted, not only the class, but all your field hierarchy (classes of fields, and the classes of their fields) must be `Serializable`)

Comment: And you have to test your classes trying to serialize them (it is, using them trough the RMI service). If your class implements Serializable but it contains a non-Serializable (non-transient) field, kaboom!

Comment: just added the Serializable. code follows! hm how do i test the serializable and what are the properties there which i have to take care about . i have no idea. in my eyes everything is seralizable :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   vsys.ue04.server.RemoteChargeImplementation

There's your problem. That class is required at the client.